# Migration to 2013 - Object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-migration

I´m currently migrating from SharePoint 2007 (via 2010) to 2013 by attaching the content databases.

Before i wanted to migrate the last websitecollection, I started the integrity check in the sitesettings;there were some warnings about document templates(template.doc). So I replaced the templates by a new one. After re-performing the integrity check, no errors were displayed.

After starting the upgrade process I checked the timerjob, which is respnsoble for migrating the websitecollecteion.
The error was : "Object reference not set to an instance of object".

Because the error is not really informative, I wanted to ask if anyone knows (from experience),where the problem could be?

LOG:

```
08/19/2014 15:19:33.66  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://sharepoint-3:8090/_layouts/siteupgradestatus.aspx)). Parent No     
08/19/2014 15:19:33.66  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://sharepoint-3:8090/_layouts/siteupgradestatus.aspx) 9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.66  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0   9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.66  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& d... 9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67* w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...bres)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermM...  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67* w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...ask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String...  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67* w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwV...  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67* w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...ersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64&...  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67* w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ... bytes, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initi...  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67* w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...alState, String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)     bei System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     bei System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     bei System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBu...  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67* w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...ildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     bei System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     bei System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()     bei System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.Proce...  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67* w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...ssRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     bei System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     bei System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObject...  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67* w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...sPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     bei System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     bei System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     bei System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     bei System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     bei System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleDa...  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67* w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...ta, Int32 flags)     9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           aiv4w   Medium      Spent 0 ms to bind 32455 byte file stream   9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.67  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Menüband rendern). Parent Request (GET:http://sharepoint-3:8090/_layouts/siteupgradestatus.aspx)  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.69  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Menüband rendern). Ausführungszeit=1,04105410045131    9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.69  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,1 agb9s,12 ak8dj,14 nasq,1 b4ly    9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.69  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x2D9C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://sharepoint-3:8090/_layouts/siteupgradestatus.aspx)). Ausführungszeit=30,5582832454963  9009b09c-f791-c087-4e35-144e3c8bf9ec
08/19/2014 15:19:33.69  w3wp.exe (0x3A50)                           0x0A24  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: (none)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it: I installed the DocumentReviewDiscussionList-Feature in SP 2013 via PowerShell.
It work´s.

Comment: If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

without debugging the timerjob service it would be hard to tell as there are many jobs running, so it could be unrelated to the upgrade.

2010 is the interim to getting to 2013. You dont need to change the document templates on 2010 but rather on 2013 if its needed.

is it on 2010 server that your getting the error or 2013? 2010 its not a big issue... if its on 2013 its also not a big issue as the upgrade would complete.... you need to check the upgrade log if its a huge concern or business critical.... if on a test server which it should be than you can upgrade from 2007 to 2010 and then to 2013, on 2013 check the upgrade log once finished upgrading it would be within the hive files under logs and it produces two files - one is the full upgrade log and the other is only errors.... this will show where its gone wrong (site/web) if atall and whats needed (file/assets ect)....

let me know how it goes and if you need help with the log, just update your question with the log output of the error..

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering.
I checked the error log from the upgrade sequence:

```
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
08/20/2014 15:58:53.15  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bj   INFO    SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.15  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bj   ERROR   Feature upgrade action 'AddContentTypeField' threw an exception upgrading Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162') in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080': Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden.     365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.40  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPSiteWssSequence2  ajy6m   INFO    SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.40  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPSiteWssSequence2  ajy6m   ERROR   Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162') in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'. Exception: Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden.     365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoe   INFO    No context object   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoe   ERROR   RunUpgradeSiteSession [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080] failed.   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoe   INFO    No context object   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoe   ERROR   Exception: Das Upgrade wurde mit Fehlern abgeschlossen. Überprüfen Sie die Upgradeprotokolldatei unter 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS\SiteUpgrade-20140820-155851-832.log'. Die Anzahl der Fehler und Warnungen ist am Ende der Updateprotokolldatei aufgeführt. 365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoe   INFO    No context object   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoe   ERROR      bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.CheckPoint()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.LogEnd()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.RunUpgradeSiteSessionCore(Object lockObject, SPSite site, SPUpgradeOperationFlags upgradeOperationFlags, Boolean checkConcurrentSiteUpgradeSession) 365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
```

And here are the logs from file SiteUpgrade-20140820-155851-832.log:

```
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxlm   INFO    ======================================================================================  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxln   INFO    Upgrade session starts  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxlo   INFO    Command line: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxlr   INFO    Mode: InPlace   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxls   INFO    Current SharePoint Build: 15.0.4569.1000    365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    aloom   INFO    Upgrade SPSite ID: [8ff29a63-31eb-4542-a928-489b418ec4fc]   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    aloon   INFO    Upgrade SPSite Subscription ID: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxlx   INFO    Upgrade Object: SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxly   INFO    Upgrade Operation Flags: Recursive V2VSiteUpgrade   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxl0   INFO    ======================================================================================  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.83  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxhf   INFO    Start upgrading [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080] with version 15.0.35.0. 365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.84  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPWebTemplateSequenceForSite    ajy7f   INFO    Template STS#0: Web template upgrade for web/site http://sharepoint:8080 returned NeedsUpgrade false. Not upgrading. Web template: STS#0, web template version: 3.0.0.2, target web template version: 15.0.0.3  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.86  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2a5   INFO    Beginning upgrade for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 < 15.0.6.0 definition version in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:51.86  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bh   INFO    Performing feature upgrade action AddContentTypeField applying to version range [null, 15.0.5.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080' 365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.15  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bj   ERROR   Feature upgrade action 'AddContentTypeField' threw an exception upgrading Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162') in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080': Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden.     365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.20  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bh   INFO    Performing feature upgrade action ApplyElementManifests applying to version range [null, 15.0.5.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.25  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bi   INFO    Completed feature upgrade action ApplyElementManifests applying to version range [null, 15.0.5.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'    365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.25  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bh   INFO    Performing feature upgrade action AddContentTypeField applying to version range [null, 15.0.5.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080' 365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.29  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bi   INFO    Completed feature upgrade action AddContentTypeField applying to version range [null, 15.0.5.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.29  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bh   INFO    Performing feature upgrade action CustomUpgradeAction.ReorderTaskContentType applying to version range [null, 15.0.3.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.29  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentTypesUpgradeFeatureReceiver    ajy2h   INFO    Loading content type schema file from C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Template\Features\ctypes\ctypeswss.xml    365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.29  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentTypesUpgradeFeatureReceiver    ajy2i   INFO    Found 10 elements in the unghosted schema for the Tasks content type    365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.34  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentTypesUpgradeFeatureReceiver    ajy2j   INFO    Found task content type in web http://sharepoint:8080   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.34  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bi   INFO    Completed feature upgrade action CustomUpgradeAction.ReorderTaskContentType applying to version range [null, 15.0.3.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:53.34  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bh   INFO    Performing feature upgrade action AddContentTypeField applying to version range [null, 15.0.4.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080' 365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.32  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bi   INFO    Completed feature upgrade action AddContentTypeField applying to version range [null, 15.0.4.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.35  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bh   INFO    Performing feature upgrade action CustomUpgradeAction.ChangeTaskFormTemplates applying to version range [null, 15.0.6.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080' 365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.35  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentTypesUpgradeFeatureReceiver    aj4ao   INFO    Loading content type schema file from C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Template\Features\ctypes\ctypeswss.xml    365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.40  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPContentTypesUpgradeFeatureReceiver    aj4ap   INFO    Found task content type in web http://sharepoint:8080   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.40  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2bi   INFO    Completed feature upgrade action CustomUpgradeAction.ChangeTaskFormTemplates applying to version range [null, 15.0.6.0) for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.40  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPFeatureDefinition aj2be   INFO    Ending upgrade for [Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162')] with instance version 14.0.1.0 and definition version 15.0.6.0 in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.40  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPSiteWssSequence2  ajy6m   ERROR   Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'CTypes' (Id: 15/'695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162') in Site 'http://sharepoint:8080'. Exception: Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. Das Feature '75a0fea7-3cc9-4c20-bf74-9bfa9fd5d614' für die Listenvorlage '1011' ist in dieser Farm nicht installiert. Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden.     365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.43  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPSiteWssSequence   ajyxy   INFO    [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080] SchemaVersion = 15.0.35.0.  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.43  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   WebAnalyticsSiteSequence    ajyxy   INFO    [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080] SchemaVersion = 15.0.1.0.   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.43  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   MossSiteSequence    ajyxy   INFO    [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080] SchemaVersion = 15.0.1.0.   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.43  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   DlcSiteSequence ajyxy   INFO    [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080] SchemaVersion = 15.0.1.0.   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.43  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SiteSequence    ajyxy   INFO    [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080] SchemaVersion = 15.0.2.0.   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.43  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   ExcelMobileViewerSiteSequence   ajyxy   INFO    [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080] SchemaVersion = 14.0.1.0.   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.43  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SiteSequence    ajyxy   INFO    [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080] SchemaVersion = 14.0.1.0.   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxhh   INFO    Finished upgrading [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080]. 365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoe   ERROR   RunUpgradeSiteSession [SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:8080] failed.   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoe   ERROR   Exception: Das Upgrade wurde mit Fehlern abgeschlossen. Überprüfen Sie die Upgradeprotokolldatei unter 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS\SiteUpgrade-20140820-155851-832.log'. Die Anzahl der Fehler und Warnungen ist am Ende der Updateprotokolldatei aufgeführt. 365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoe   ERROR      bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.CheckPoint()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.LogEnd()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.RunUpgradeSiteSessionCore(Object lockObject, SPSite site, SPUpgradeOperationFlags upgradeOperationFlags, Boolean checkConcurrentSiteUpgradeSession) 365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.67  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxl4   INFO    ======================================================================================  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.68  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxl5   INFO    Upgrade session failed. 5 errors and 0 warnings encountered.    365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.68  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxl6   INFO    Suchen Sie nach möglichen Ursachen für Upgradeprobleme, indem Sie die Zeichenfolgen [ERROR] und [WARNING] in der Upgradeprotokolldatei durchsuchen. Weitere Informationen zur Wiederherstellung nach Upgradefehlern finden Sie unter "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=259653".   365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
08/20/2014 15:58:54.68  OWSTIMER (0x2D74)   0x1744  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSiteSession    ajxl7   INFO    ======================================================================================  365eb09c-870a-c087-4e35-1223c526a3c8
```

Any ideas?
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
So i found out the name of the missing feature on the SP2007 machine in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\DocumentReviewListInstances\ListInstances.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <ListInstance FeatureId="75A0FEA7-775B-4ae1-BBC6-AD5EF0D22413" TemplateType="101" Title="$Resources:tsa,DRDocumentsForReviewListFolder;" Url="Documents for Review" OnQuickLaunch="TRUE" />
        <ListInstance FeatureId="**75A0FEA7-3CC9-4c20-BF74-9BFA9FD5D614**" TemplateType="1011" Title="$Resources:tsa,DRReviewDiscussionList;" Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/Review Discussions" />
        <ListInstance FeatureId="00BFEA71-D1CE-42de-9C63-A44004CE0104" TemplateType="104" Title="$Resources:core,announceList;" Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,announce_Folder;">
        <Data>
          <Rows>
            <Row>
              <Field Name="Title">$Resources:core,onetid11;</Field>
              <Field Name="Body">$Resources:core,onetid12;</Field>
              <Field Name="Expires">&lt;ows:TodayISO/&gt;</Field>
            </Row>
          </Rows>
        </Data>
      </ListInstance>
    </Elements>
```

I don´t know what to do with the information *Title="$Resources:tsa,DRReviewDiscussionList;" Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/Review Discussions"*

So, I copied the folder DocumentReviewListInstances to SP 2013 and installed the feature via powershell: Install-SPFeature -path "DocumentReviewListInstances".

After that i started the upgrade via website settings, but the same error occured.